# Scrapy: How to use scraped item as variable for dynamic URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to start the scraping on the last number of pagination. From Highest page to lowest

https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/page-

page-2267 is dynamic so I need to scrape the item first before I determine the last-page number, and then the url pagination should go like this page-2267 , page-2266...

here's what I have done

```
class TeslamotorsclubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'teslamotorsclub'
    allowed_domains = ['teslamotorsclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/']

    def parse(self, response):
        last_page = response.xpath('//div[@class = "PageNav"]/@data-last').extract_first()
        for item in response.css("[id^='fc-post-']"):
            last_page = response.xpath('//div[@class = "PageNav"]/@data-last').extract_first()
            datime = item.css("a.datePermalink span::attr(title)").get()
            message = item.css('div.messageContent blockquote').extract()
            datime = parser.parse(datime)
            yield {"last_page":last_page,"message":message,"datatime":datime}

        next_page = 'https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/page-' + str(TeslamotorsclubSpider.last_page)
        print(next_page)
        TeslamotorsclubSpider.last_page = int(TeslamotorsclubSpider.last_page)
        TeslamotorsclubSpider.last_page -= 1
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I need to scrape items from highest page to lowest.
Please help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of last page to first page, try the following:

```
class TeslamotorsclubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'teslamotorsclub'
    start_urls = ['https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/']
    page_start = 'https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/page-{}'
    cbool = False

    def parse(self, response):
        if not self.cbool:
            last_page = response.xpath('//div[@class = "PageNav"]/@data-last').extract_first()
            self.cbool = True
            yield response.follow(self.page_start.format(int(last_page)), callback=self.parse)

        else:
            for item in response.css("[id^='fc-post-']"):
                message = item.css('div.messageContent blockquote::text').extract()
                yield {"message":message} 

            prev_page = response.css("[class='PageNav'] a:contains('Prev')::attr('href')").get()
            yield {"prev_page":prev_page} #Check it whether it is working
            if prev_page:
                yield response.follow(prev_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: 2268 is dynamic I cannot constantly dictate 2268 there

Comment: Check out the update. It should work now @Christian Read.

Comment: Hi @SIM this one works well thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

You have very good element on your page `link[rel=next]`. So you can refactor your code in this way: parse page, call next, parse page, call next, etc.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.css("[id^='fc-post-']"):
        datime = item.css("a.datePermalink span::attr(title)").get()
        message = item.css('div.messageContent blockquote').extract()
        datime = parser.parse(datime)
        yield {"message":message,"datatime":datime}

    next_page = response.css('link[rel=next]::attr(href)').get()
    if next_page:
        yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

UPD: here is code that scrapes data from last page to first:

```
class TeslamotorsclubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'teslamotorsclub'
    allowed_domains = ['teslamotorsclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/']
    next_page = 'https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/page-{}'

    def parse(self, response):
        last_page = response.xpath('//div[@class = "PageNav"]/@data-last').get()
        if last_page and int(last_page):
            # iterate from last page down to first
            for i in range(int(last_page), 0, -1):
                url = self.next_page.format(i)
                yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # parse data on page
        for item in response.css("[id^='fc-post-']"):
            last_page = response.xpath('//div[@class = "PageNav"]/@data-last').get()
            datime = item.css("a.datePermalink span::attr(title)").get()
            message = item.css('div.messageContent blockquote').extract()
            datime = parser.parse(datime)
            yield {"last_page":last_page,"message":message,"datatime":datime}
```

Comment: Spot that you unmarked this answer as accepted. Just interesting, did you find any other problem?

Comment: yes sorry I really still need to start on the end of the page since the page has 2000+ pages , I have if statement that needs to filter the latest 24hours post. If I will start on first page (oldest post) It took several time to finish my scrape. Any idea please

Comment: Hi @vezunchik just have a problem on the logic of your code and found out some problem, but I gave you 1 for helping me thank you

Answer (score 0):

I use the next algorithm to resolve it:

Start on First page.

```
url = url_page1

xpath_next_page = "//div[@class='pageNavLinkGroup']//a[@class='text' and contains(text(), 'Next')]"
```

Load first page, Do your stuff, at the end check if that XPATH is present on HTML and page+=1.

Comment: Hi @Wonka I still need to start the scrape at the last page I cannot start it from page 1 because its a waste of time, it has 2000+ pages